# Is it possible to have vertical type in LWUIT?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, typography

I need to display text vertically, either rotated 90 degrees or one letter stacked on top of another. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Draw your text in Image and rotate image as you wish.
2) For drawing one letter on top of another you can have to create custom component and override paint method.